# HTTP 404 Error setting hooking up Google's Cloud Run to Firebase Hosting

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-run

I was following this guide https://medium.com/firebase-developers/hosting-flask-servers-on-firebase-from-scratch-c97cfb204579 and I'm stuck on firebase's `./node_modules/.bin/firebase serve` command

I was successfully able to deploy the project using Cloud Run and get a service url that is working for the site, but when I try and serve it locally it produces this error on the static page when running to localhost:5000:

> A problem occurred while trying to handle a proxied rewrite: error looking up URL for Cloud Run service: FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 404, Resource 'flask-fire' of kind 'SERVICE' in region 'us-central1' in project 'cjcflaskapp10192021' does not exist.

Here is my firebase.json file.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "static",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "run": {
        "serviceId": "flask-fire"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: You try to call localhost:5000 from your computer? But you should call the Cloud Run service isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [article comments](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/hosting-flask-servers-on-firebase-from-scratch-c97cfb204579) I discovered several users who also experienced the same error, one comment in special refers to a region mismatch between Firebase Hosting and the Cloud Run service:

> Looks like the region selection is an important step. Because in the first step, I deployed the server side code ( app.py ) in region us-west-1 and it worked fine. But after setting up the firebase deployment setup, it strangely looked up for my URL in region us-central1.
> Error Log :
> A problem occurred while trying to handle a proxied rewrite: error looking up URL for Cloud Run service: FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 404, Resource 'flask-simple-pwa' of kind 'SERVICE' in region 'us-central1' in project 'flask-simple-pwa' does not exist.
> When I checked the documentation for firebase, in Location us-west1 is nowhere to be seen .
> It could be that this has changed since the time you wrote the article. Is this something that you can verify?

There is an [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#direct_requests_to_container) on how to serve dynamic content from Cloud Run to use with Firebase Hosting, which is more complete and it explains that a region should be set on `firebase.json` that matches the region of your current Cloud Run deployment. If no region is set, FIrebase hosting will default to `us-central1`.

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [{
    "source": "/helloworld",
    "run": {
      "serviceId": "helloworld",  // "service name" (from when you deployed the container image)
      "region": "us-central1"     // optional (if omitted, default is us-central1)
    }
  }]
}
```

If this does not match with your Cloud Run deployment, it can cause this error. For a list of supported locations for Firebase, you can refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations) page.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer from ErnestoC is correct.

I had the same issue and figured I had to choose e.g. europe-west3 as my region for the Flask API.

Thank you!

Comment: We prefer if you don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31311640)